# Merge of Skip Lists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, merge, skip-lists

How can I merge 2 given `Skip lists` (each with n keys) into a one single `Skip List` in `O(n)` time complexity (worst case)?

Just looking for the algorithm - no particular implementation/language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
store the two skip lists in two arrays: A,B
merge the arrays.
repeat until getting into root ('top' is a linked list containing only one element): 
   for each second entry in the skip list 'top' add a 'tag' (link 'upstairs' of the previous level)
```

it is indeed O(n) because store and merge are O(n), and in the loop, you need to iterate over:

```
n+n/2+n/4+n/8+... = sigma(n/2^k) where k in (0,infinity) = 2n
```

Comment: I am not sure I used the skip-list`s terms properly (in the loop) I am sure this solution is correct however. let me know if you don't understand something.